# In Logan's Run (1976) how does controlling the population work when it comes to births?

Tags: plot-explanation, logans-run

I recently rewatched [*Logan's Run*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074812/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). The concept of "Carousel" is explained well. Citizens participate when they turn 30 and believe they will be able to renew (be reborn) and it is shown later that the process is a hoax and no one is actually reborn.

If the point of carousel is population control then how does the city account for births? Early in the film Francis tells Logan that when one completes another is born. We know that there is no renewal, but is the population controlled in such a way that there is approximately a birth for every death? I have not read the novel. Does it explain that there? Does Francis know there is a birth for every death or are we assuming this is another lie the people have been fed and that he has chosen to believe it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be noted that the original book is **significantly** different from the movie so answers are unlikely to be found there.

As for the movie, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run_(film)) states

> In the year 2274, the remnants of human civilization live in a sealed city contained beneath a cluster of geodesic domes, a utopia run by a computer that takes care of all aspects of life, **including reproduction**

There is brief confirmation that the parents **do not even meet** [in the dialogue](https://sfy.ru/?script=logans_run) so it seems likely that reproduction is handled through artificial means and so population growth can be strictly controlled

> ```
>       FRANCIS
>
> I don't know what makes you so curious.
> You have any idea who his seed-mother was?
>
>       LOGAN (quickly)
> Of course not! I m curious, not sick.
>       (laughs)
> ```